# Searching for a particular dungeon adventure

Tags: published-adventures, dnd-3e, dungeon

In the D&D 3.0 *Dungeon Master's Guide* there is a sample dungeon (p. 126) that has only the first three rooms detailed. This is the dungeon where Lidda (infamously) gets eaten by ghouls in the example of play (p. 130). This dungeon is also a re-write of the sample dungeon that appeared in the AD&D 1st edition *Dungeon Masters Guide*. (Note that the dungeon was removed in the *DMG v3.5*.)

A few years ago I discovered that someone had done a complete write-up for 3.x of that sample dungeon and fleshed it out into a full-fledged adventure. The author had apparently used the random encounter-generation tables in the DMG to fill out the dungeon to see if a coherent adventure could be formed out of the results, and it looked pretty good. The dungeon had been themed as the ruins of a monastery of fire-themed monks, and there was a chamber at the very end that contained the fabled fist-sized ruby of those monks. I seem to recall that there was even a dragon lurking in the dungeon somewhere too.

I cannot for the life of me find this adventure now, regardless of what I ask Google.

Does anyone know the name of this dungeon adventure and where to find it?

Comment: Sorry my search-fu failed me too. The only searches for any of the text from the sample just turn up the sample, the writer obviously didn't reuse any text word for word.

Comment: Yeah. My hope is that someone actively remembers this and either has the URL or knows that it's disappeared into the ether.

Comment: You can still pick up issue 84 of dungeon for like $5.  Check out this map to see if it looks familiar.  http://s193.photobucket.com/albums/z17/tmpiper/?action=view&current=FireOpalDungeon.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be that you meant the *Dungeon of the Fire Opal* by Jonathan Tweet?

It was published in **Dungeon #84** in an 18-page article, starting at page 106. It has the gem you described, the monastery theme, undead monks and a Fiendish Red Wyrmling.

Comment: OMG I think you got it.  Great job! +1

Comment: That's it! Now how the heck did I think that was online somewhere? Now that I look it up in *Dungeon* #84 I remember there being more discussion of the design method from the author when I first read it, so maybe an now-disappeared blog post. Thanks!